# pandas dynamic wide to long based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transformation

I have pandas dataframe that contains data given below

```
  ID  Q1_rev  Q1_transcnt Q2_rev  Q2_transcnt Q3_rev  Q3_transcnt Q4_rev  Q4_transcnt
1   100        2         200       4         300       6          400     8
2   101        3         201       5         301       7          401     9
```

dataframe looks like below

[image]

I would like to do the below

a) For each ID, create 3 rows (from 8 input columns data)

b) Each row should contain the two columns data

c) subsequent rows should shift the columns by 1 (one quarter data).

To understand better, I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

I tried the below based on the SO post here but unable to get the expected output

```
s = 3
n = 2

cols = ['1st_rev','1st_transcnt','2nd_rev','2nd_transcnt']

output = pd.concat((df.iloc[:,0+i*s:6+i*s].set_axis(cols, axis=1) for i in range(int((df.shape[1]-(s*n))/n))), ignore_index=True, axis=0).set_index(np.tile(df.index,2))
```

Can help me with this? The problem is in real time, `n=2` will not be the case. It could be 4 or 5 as well. Meaning, Instead of `'1st_rev','1st_transcnt','2nd_rev','2nd_transcnt'`, I may have the below. You can see there are 4 pairs of columns.

```
'1st_rev','1st_transcnt','2nd_rev','2nd_transcnt','3rd_rev','3rd_transcnt','4th_rev','4th_transcnt'
```

Comment: Your input data and expected of don't align. Where does qty columns go to? Kindly update your expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy - updated the input data

Comment: What is the Expected output dataframe for 3?

Comment: You can see the below answer by Jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by splitted columns names by `_` and selected second splitted substring by `x.split('_')[1]`:

```
N = 2
df1 = df.set_index('ID')

def f(x,n=N):
    out = np.array([[list(L[x:x+n]) for x in range(len(L)-n+1)] for L in x.to_numpy()])
    return pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(out))
       
df2 = (df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1, sort=False)
           .apply(f)
           .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False))

df2.index = np.repeat(df1.index, int(len(df2.index) / len(df1.index)))
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1] + 1}_{x[0]}')
print (df2)
    1_rev  1_transcnt  2_rev  2_transcnt
ID                                      
1     100           2    200           4
1     200           4    300           6
1     300           6    400           8
2     101           3    201           5
2     201           5    301           7
2     301           7    401           9
```

Test with 3 window:

```
N = 3
df1 = df.set_index('ID')

def f(x,n=N):
    out = np.array([[list(L[x:x+n]) for x in range(len(L)-n+1)] for L in x.to_numpy()])
    return pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(out))
       
df2 = (df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1, sort=False)
           .apply(f)
           .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False))

df2.index = np.repeat(df1.index, int(len(df2.index) / len(df1.index)))
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1] + 1}_{x[0]}')
print (df2)
    1_rev  1_transcnt  2_rev  2_transcnt  3_rev  3_transcnt
ID                                                         
1     100           2    200           4    300           6
1     200           4    300           6    400           8
2     101           3    201           5    301           7
2     201           5    301           7    401           9
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. Nice, it works. One doubt. If I increase the number of columns to `3` , the order of columns is bit messed up. Is it possible to reorder the columns. So that `rev, qty and transcnt`. See the updated input data

Comment: @TheGreat - If add `sort_remaining=False` to `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False))` it working?

Comment: Is this something that you would be able to help me with? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142234/pandas-merge-using-list-columns-and-contains-operation

Answer (score 1):

One option is with a for loop or list comprehension, followed by a concatenation, and a sort:

```py
temp = df.set_index('ID')
cols = ['1st_rev','1st_transcnt','2nd_rev','2nd_transcnt']
outcome = [temp
          .iloc(axis=1)[n:n+4]
          .set_axis(cols, axis = 1)
          for n in range(0, len(cols)+2, 2)]
pd.concat(outcome).sort_index()

    1st_rev  1st_transcnt  2nd_rev  2nd_transcnt
ID                                              
1       100             2      200             4
1       200             4      300             6
1       300             6      400             8
2       101             3      201             5
2       201             5      301             7
2       301             7      401             9
```

To make it more generic, a while loop can be used (you can use a for loop - a while loop seems more readable/easier to understand):

```py
def reshape_N(df, N):
    # you can pass your custom column names here instead
    # as long as it matches the width
    # of the dataframe
    columns = ['rev', 'transcnt']
    columns = np.tile(columns, N)
    numbers = np.arange(1, N+1).repeat(2)
    columns = [f"{n}_{ent}" 
               for n, ent 
               in zip(numbers, columns)]
    contents = []
    start = 0
    end = N * 2
    temp = df.set_index("ID")
    while (end < temp.columns.size):
        end += start
        frame = temp.iloc(axis=1)[start:end]
        frame.columns = columns
        contents.append(frame)
        start += 2
    if not contents:
        return df
    return pd.concat(contents).sort_index()
```

let's apply the function:

```py
reshape_N(df, 2)
    1_rev  1_transcnt  2_rev  2_transcnt
ID                                      
1     100           2    200           4
1     200           4    300           6
1     300           6    400           8
2     101           3    201           5
2     201           5    301           7
2     301           7    401           9

reshape_N(df, 3)
    1_rev  1_transcnt  2_rev  2_transcnt  3_rev  3_transcnt
ID                                                         
1     100           2    200           4    300           6
1     200           4    300           6    400           8
2     101           3    201           5    301           7
2     201           5    301           7    401           9
```

Comment: Nice. If we are to try with N=3 window, which one would you change?

Comment: updated the code with a generic function that handles case where N = 3